# Spring Managed Custom Validator not being used from endpoint

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I've been at this for a while, but I have a Spring managed custom validator that looks like the below, I have some print statements in there which I'll get to later

```
@Component
public class BulkUpdateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidBulkUpdate, BulkUpdate> {
  @Autowired
  ObjectMapper mapper;

  public BulkUpdateValidator(){
    System.out.println(this.toString());
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void post(){
    System.out.println(mapper);
    System.out.println(this.toString());
  }

  public boolean isValid(BulkUpdate update, ConstraintValidatorContext context){
    System.out.println(this.toString());
    System.out.println(mapper);
  }
  ... other validator methods ...
}
```

My controller method: (NOTE: my controller class is annotated with @Validated at the top)

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public @ResponseBody RestResponse bulkUpdate(@Valid @ValidBulkUpdate Bulkupdate bulkUpdate){
  ... stuff here ...
}
```

My Bean:

```
public class BulkUpdate {
  @NotEmpty
  public List<String> recordIds;

  @NotEmpty
  @Valid
  public List<FieldUpdate> updates;

  .... getters and setters ....
}
```

Here's my problem, when I execute the endpoint it get a NullPointerException when I attempt to use the autowired mapper. The output from the print statements I posted above are quite telling. In both the constructor and the @PostConstruct sections I get the same Object ID for the validator and I also get an ID for the mapper. However, once isValid is called, it prints out a different Object ID. I know the spring managed validator is being created, but it's not being used.

Furthermore, I've tried to remove the @ValidBulkUpdate annotation from the REST endpoint and put it inside a wrapper object, thinking that maybe @Valid was necessary to get spring to take over, like below:

```
public @ResponseBody RestResponse bulkUpdate(@Valid BulkupdateWrapper bulkUpdate){
```

... stuff here ...
}

And wrapper

```
public class BulkUpdateWrapper {
  @ValidBulkUpdate
  private BulkUpdate update;

  .... getter and setter ....
}
```

This leaves me with a whole new error which is even weirder:

"JSR-303 validated property 'update.org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConstraintViolationImpl' does not have a corresponding accessor"

I'm not sure where to turn, hopefully someone has an idea. Either how to get it to use the Spring managed validator, or how to remove that vague error when I use the object wrapper;

What's worse, is I have MockMvc based Integration tests for this that run flawlessly, this only happens when I deploy it.

**UPDATE**

So I kept my wrapper and changed @Valid to @Validated and now my error is the following: "NotReadablePropertyException: Bean property 'update.field' does not have a corresponding accessor for Spring data binding"

Fun fact, there is no property called "field"